# memory error, but only on device running ios 8

Tags: realm

My app running on an iPhone 4 iOS 8.3 gets this error:

> 2016-06-26 19:09:22.587 Skyline Flora[4498:949043] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'mmap() failed:
>   Cannot allocate memory size: 671088640 offset: 0'
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>
> (0x29cd5d67 0x37534c77 0x2318db 0x211d03 0x21231b 0x212c41 0x2113fd
>   0x15354f 0x153133 0x152fbf 0xbea6b 0x2d17a705 0x2d2245a5 0x2d2244cd
>   0x2d223a51 0x2d22378b 0x2d2234f1 0x2d223489 0x2d177c1f 0x2cba2f65
>   0x2cb9e951 0x2cb9e7d9 0x2cb9e1c7 0x2cb9dfd1 0x2d3dba5d 0x2d3dc7f5
>   0x2d3e6c39 0x2d3dac2b 0x304470e1 0x29c9c60d 0x29c9b8d1 0x29c9a06f
>   0x29be7981 0x29be7793 0x2d1deb87 0x2d1d9981 0xbfa1b 0x37ad0aaf)
>
> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

It only happens on the device, it's fine in the simulator (Xcode 7.3).

The phone has 18GB free when the app is run.

This error has shown up in the past, as can be found easily with a search, but on writes; this app only reads the database, never writes.

There's no problem on iOS 9 devices.

What's the next thing to check?

Comment: Is the phone in question an iPhone 4 or iPhone 4S? The iPhone 4 doesn't run anything past iOS 7, as far as I know.

Comment: My typo - it's a 4S

Answer (score 0):

The Realm file is `mmap`ed whether it is opened as read-only or read-write. Unfortunately, this is probably an issue inherent to the resource constraints of the iPhone 4/4S. We've seen issues with `mmap` ranging from files as small as 300 MB, depending on the device.

You can check out [this Github issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3226#issuecomment-185901012) for some potential workarounds.

Comment: OK, thanks. Given that it only happens on iOS 8 devices, and iOS 10 being imminent, it doesn't make sense to go through a whole lot of dev and testing for a small set of devices.